# Block image from be viewd/download in every browser

Tags: .htaccess

I need to provide a texture URL that will be used in an online game (with a desktop software) and I need to prevent people to open the texture from their browsers and allow the texture to be opened only by that game.

The game is quite similar to Second Life, it uses part of the same engine.

I don't need an anti hacker method, just a way to prevent users that have the URL from open it in browsers.

I know someone that has done it but I don't know how, but I know is possible.

I think I need to check the HTTP header with .htaccess and filter somehow but I've not idea how.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a secret `QUERY_STRING` parameter while making an HTTP request from the desktop software. The `htaccess` can check this parameter name/value and grant access accordingly. If all your textures were present at `/textures` your `htaccess` would look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/textures [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)password(=|&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

---

If the request URL is beyond your control, you need to look at things like IP Address (in case of a static IP), or software's `User-Agent` HTTP header that can be used to uniquely identify and grant access to it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !software_id [NC]
```

Here, `software_id` denotes some part of your software's `User-Agent`. For example, to grant access only to iPhones one would use `!iphone [NC]` above.

Comment: I've not access to the desktop software, I can just use the pre-made tools, and for textures is just a link.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Without something differentiating a request coming from the software from the ones coming from a browser, you can't decide whether to allow access or not. There has to be something like IP Address (won't work 'coz I believe a software can have any number of installations), User Agent etc. but none of these would work if you don't have access to the desktop software.

Comment: I can make a "php image" and sniff the user agent of the software probably. I will try

Comment: Well, you lived up to your username! :) Good job mate.